# Trying to create simple login test case from Selenium using Python in Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I observe that when I click on submit form after entering username and password, username and password fields get blanked and my test case is shown as success although login process does not complete.

If I manually enter username and password in firefox opened by webdriver, I get same problem again.

But if I enter username password in another firefox session opened manually through terminal, I am able to successfully login.

I suspect some javascript is being blocked by selenium, which does not allow me to login. No error message comes anytime.

Comment: Initially try to use some wait.  and if even it is not solving your issue then use javasciptExecutor for enter data in your field and  for click too. Give your HTML code structure so I can create a script for you

Comment: Can you link the page so that we can take a look?

Comment: comments section does not allow much characters. <td/>
<td class="custom-button" align="left">
<a onclick="checkForm(document.loginform);" name="j_security_check" title="Submit form" href="javascript://" marked="1">                                  Submit                                   </a>
</td>
</tr> In this segment I found Submit button from Xpath which is .//*[@id='central-section']/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a  and thereafter I used .click(). But username and password fields got blanked. I could however find a getaround and send return keys after password. But this issue remains.

Comment: Xpath was found from firebug, so I do not see an issue with that.